# How to wait for a button to complete its task then execute the next line of code

Tags: javascript

I have a button as follows that I programmatically click.

```
document.getElementById("generateButton").click();
```

This button creates a table and loads the data from the database.

I then have options to sort the table that if specified in the url, the table will be sorted once loaded.

```
if(COL_ONE == "true")
            sortTable("COL_ONE");
```

My problem is that the table takes around 3 seconds to load. Therefore, the if statement where the sorting happens, ends up running before the table is created. Therefore, the sorting does not occur. If I place a break point at the if statement and stop execution at the if statement, and wait until I see the table load, then run the if statement (through the debugger) then my sorting does work. Therefore, the code is all working, its just a matter of figuring out a way to stall until the table is loaded. Is there anyway I can do this, where until the table is loaded, then run the next if statement, I am doing this on page load.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185515/make-javascript-function-callback-ish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of callback in this case

```
function tableLoaded(callback) {
   //Code to load the table
   callback();
}
```

In your main function

```
tableLoaded(function(){
   //have your if statement
   if(COL_ONE == "true")
      sortTable("COL_ONE");
});
```

Comment: in the code to load table would I place document.getElementById("generateButton").click();

Comment: you would have this call in the function which you had previously written to load the table. To load the table you need to have this function where you would specify the callback

Comment: Im still a bit confused as to where the getElementById("generateButton").click(); would go. In my original question, I have all that in a single function. So from my understaning, I am putting the tableLoaded in a separeate function, and the tableLoaded(function()) in my original method?

Comment: yes you are right @user3767481. You need to create a separate function and the teableLoaded(callback) in the original method.

Answer (score 0):

Please post the relevant DB code.

I can only guess, though, that it looks similar to this:

```
document.getElementById("generateButton").addEventListener('click', function() {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if ( xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200 ) {
        updateTable(xmlHttp.responseText);
      }
    };
    xmlHttp.open("GET", '/get-info-from-db', true);
    xmlHttp.send();
});
```

In which case, it is a simple change:

```
document.getElementById("generateButton").addEventListener('click', function() {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if ( xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200 ) {
        updateTable(xmlHttp.responseText);
        if(COL_ONE == "true")
          sortTable("COL_ONE");
      }
    };
    xmlHttp.open("GET", '/get-info-from-db', true);
    xmlHttp.send();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely must put the sorting functionality in a callback and set it up to be called after the data loads. I noticed you might be loading the data into the tables asynchronously, i.e. loading data in a callback function, which is probably why the sorting function is kicking in before the load.. don't do that, have the sorting to excute right after call the function to load data.. Prehaps it would be better if you told me how you are loading the data so i can tell you extactly when and where to place to the callback function with the sorting functionality. For example, if you are using third-party support to load the data, you should probably try to find in the api a function call to load data that also accepts a callback, or completion handler. For the callback, you must pass your sorting functionality in the form of an anonymous function. Hope this helps!!